# Email Not Sending ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp

We have develop an application that sends email to the user after he confirms a visit to our branch.
It works fine when we use the following Gmail configuration:
Email: ainetwgdocs@gmail.com
Passwd: XXXXX
SMTP Server: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 587
However, when we try using our domain-based account it simply dosen't work.
We are using the following parameters:
Email: contact@ainetw.com
Passwd: XXXXX
SMTP Server: smtpout.secureserver.net
Port: 465

Code snippet below:

```
 using (System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mm = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from, to))
            {
                mm.Subject = subject;
                mm.Body = body;
                mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
                System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential(from, password);
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                smtp.Host = smtpHost;
                smtp.Port = smtpPort;
                try
                {
                    smtp.Send(mm);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;  
                }                
            }
            return;
        }
```

Is there anything missing?
Suggestions are welcome.

Thx

Comment: You catch an exception, and then throw one. Maybe take a look at the actual error message if there is one?

Comment: The problem might be in google account. From your google account in “sing in and security settings” make sure less security apps enabled (it’s in bottom of security page). If you’re using 2fa you can generate a new password for the app only.

Answer (score 1):

Check the **SmtpStatusCode** first.

```
try
    {
　　client.Send(message);
    }
    catch (SmtpException e)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.StatusCode);
    }
```

Try set **EnableSsl** to **False**.

Finally, you can lookup the server your email is associated to by logging into your godaddy account, launching the email service, click on "Domains" in the left nav, the click on server addresses in the horizontal nav.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Here is what I get from the exception catch:
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' in System.dll
e.InnerException {"Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed."}
I've tried a few suggestion for the exception above but no one has solved the problem.
Additional suggestions are welcome. Thx!

Comment: Based on the exception message, you need to check your mail server and network. There are no error in the code itself. You can try another mail server or change the port and so on. And you can try port 587 instead of 465. Port 465 is technically deprecated.

Comment: Don't always send mail to one receiver, the mail maybe treated as junk mail too.